# Handle stuff after dom changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I've got a page with some Javascript / jQuery stuff, for example:

```
(function()
{
    $('.tip').tooltip();

    $('.test').click(function()
    {
        alert('Clicked!')
    });
}();
```

On the page I insert some HTML with jQuery so the DOM changes. For example, I insert a extra element with the class "tip" or "test". The just new inserted elements doesn't work because jQuery is working with the non-manipulated DOM and the just inserted elements aren't there. So I've searched around and came to this solution for the "click":

```
$('body').on('click','.click',function()
{
    alert('Clicked!')
});
```

I don't understand why, but this way it's working with the manipulated DOM and the jQuery stuff works on the new inserted elements. So my first question is, why does this work and just the click() function not? And the second question, why do I have to point to the "body"?

Finally, my third question is, how get this done with the tooltip?

I know that there is so many information about this subject (previous the delegate() and live() function I've read) but I can't found a explanation about it. And I can't get my third question solved with the information I found.

I'm looking forward to your responses!

**Extra question:**

4) Is it recommended to point always to the "body" for this kind of situations? It's always there but for possible performance issues?

Comment: `.click` adds it directly to the element. So it has to be there when you attach it. `.on` uses event bubbling. You can read all about it in the docs http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 3):

> So my first question is, why does this work and just the click()
>   function not?

Because the event handler is now delegated to a parent element, so it remains even after replacing/manipulating child elements.

Ancient article on event delegation for your perusal - but the concepts remain the same:

- http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-event-delegation-is-easier-than-you-think/

> And the second question, why do I have to point to the "body"

You don't, any suitable parent element will do. For example, any direct parent (a div wrapper, for instance) which does *not* get replaced.

> Finally, my third question is, how get this done with the tooltip?

You need to re-initialize your tooltip plugin on the newly inserted elements. For example:

```
$.get("foo.html", function (html) {
    $("#someDiv").html(html);
    $("#someDiv").find(".tip").tooltip();
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Very useful, but is it possible to bind the tooltip? Like I can do with the click event and the alert? That would be easier, so I can code DRY? And what's your opinion about my new 4th question?

Answer (score 2):

The `click()` event doesn't work when you manipulate the DOM because JQuery is not watching for DOM changes.  When you bind the `click()` event it is selecting the elements that are on the page at that time.  New ones are not in the list unless you explicitly bind the event.

Because you have pointed the `click()` event on the body.  JQuery then checks to see if the target of the click matches any of the event handlers (like what you have created) match the element clicked.  This way any new elements will get the event 'associated' with them.

Because the tooltip isn't an event that you can place on the body, you will need to re-initialize it when the element is created.

**EDIT:**

For your fourth question, is it depends.  The advantage of binding to the body is that you don't accidentally bind an event to an element more than once.  The disadvantage is that you are adding event handlers that need to be checked on each event and this can lead to performance issues.

As for your concerns about DRY, put the initialization of the tooltips into a function and call that when you add them.  Trying to avoid having the same function call is a little overkill in this regard, IMO.

Comment: Thank you too for your reply! Please see my comment on karim79 his answer too.

Comment: Thanks for you answer again! Is what I'm doing here: http://oi49.tinypic.com/2csgmdy.jpg good?

Answer (score 1):

Events are bound to the specific object you are binding it to.

So something like `$('.tip').tooltip()` will perform the tooltip() functionality on `$('.tip')` which is actually just a collection of objects that satisfies the css selector `.tip`. The thing you should take note of is, that collection is not dynamic, it is basically a "database" query of the current page, and returns a resultset of HTML DOM objects wrapped by jQuery.

Therefore calling tooptip() on that collection will only perform the tooltip functionality on the objects within that collection, anything that was not in that collection when tooltip is called will not have the tooltip functionality. So adding an element that satisfies the `.tip` selector, *after* the `tooltip()` call, will not give it the tooltip functionality.

Now, `$('body').on('click','.click', func)` is actually binding the click event to the `body` tag (which should always exist :P), but what happens is it captures whether the click event has passed through an element your target css selector (`.click` in this case), so since the check is done dynamically, new elements will be captured.

This is a relatively short summary of what's going on... I hope it helped

**UPDATE:**
Best way for your tooltip thing is to bind tooltip after you have added elements, e.g.

```
$('#container').load('www.example.com/stuff', function() {
    $('.tip', $(this)).tooltip();
});
```

Comment: Thank you too, I'll try to keep my comments DRY too, please see my comments on other answers.

Comment: Thanks again! But is it not a problem that I initialize the tooltip again? I've done this on document ready and I'm doing the same when the dom changes. Do I need to de-initialize the first time or something?

Comment: In my example, the elements i'm initializing with tooltip are all guaranteed to be new, so that's not a problem. If you are adding elements in one by one, you will have to initialize the tooltip each time you add an element to that specific element.

Comment: note: `$('.tip', $(this))` is equivalent to `$(this).find('.tip')`, which in this case is equivalent to `$('#container').find('.tip')`